# Does stackoverflow.com use dependency injection?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, technology

I know stackoverflow.com uses ASP.NET MVC but I am curious to know the design and the architecture of Stack Overflow. In particular, I am curious to know about the following design choices:

- Does it use Dependency Injection/IoC container? Why or why not?
- Where is the business logic developed? In the Controller action methods? Repository methods if following Repository pattern? Or in the Service layer if following the Service pattern? Or in the domain objects themselves à la Active Record?

In particular I would be more interested in learning about reasons pertaining specifically to stackoverflow.com rather than generic ones.

Comment: Those would be pretty lengthy controller action methods...

Comment: @Arnis, lengthy?? The question is not about length. If we were to move that same logic to Service layer - if we are using Service pattern - then the "lengthy" would still be there.

Comment: So many fancy terms

Comment: Of course SO uses dependency injection.  The site is developed with ASP.NET MVC, and the developers obviously know what they are doing...  So, why wouldn't they?